# Tool to scan web projects for unused files

Tags: code-analysis

I am looking for a script or plugin for npm/composer/vscode to scan a project for files (e.g. scripts, css, images) that are not referenced anywhere in the code, and provide a list which I can use as candidates to be deleted/deprecated for future deletion.